# CosmosDb search datetime with millisecond precision not working when ms is .0000000Z

Tags: datetime, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Have the following test data in CosmosDB.

```
{
    "LastSuccessfulDeployment": "2022-10-08T01:30:30.0000000Z",
},
{
    "LastSuccessfulDeployment": "2022-10-08T01:30:30.3816486Z",
}
```

Searching '***2022-10-08T01:30:30.0000000Z***' returns no records whereas when searching for '2022-10-08T01:30:30.3816486Z' records are being returned.

```
protected override IQueryable<Component> ApplyFiltersOnQueryInternal(IQueryable<Component> query, IFilter<Component> filter)
{
    if (filter == null)
        return query;

    var componentFilter = (filter as ComponentFilter)!;

    if (componentFilter.LastSuccessfulDeployment.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(x => x.LastSuccessfulDeployment == componentFilter.LastSuccessfulDeployment);

    return query
        .Skip((componentFilter.CurrentPage - 1) * componentFilter.PageSize)
        .Take(componentFilter.PageSize);
}
```

EntityQueryable DebugView:

```
-- @__componentFilter_LastSuccessfulDeployment_0='08/10/2022 01:30:30'
SELECT c
FROM root c
WHERE ((c["Discriminator"] = "Component") AND (c["LastSuccessfulDeployment"] = @__componentFilter_LastSuccessfulDeployment_0))
```

````
-- @__componentFilter_LastSuccessfulDeployment_0='12/10/2022 15:18:14'
SELECT c
FROM root c
WHERE ((c["Discriminator"] = "Component") AND (c["LastSuccessfulDeployment"] = @__componentFilter_LastSuccessfulDeployment_0))
```Code
````

Comment: Please edit to show your actual query - as written, you haven't included that. Also note that there is no time precision here, since your timestamp properties are strings, not actual dates (this could be an issue with your code converting those strings to `DateTime` objects). What happens when you try to find your content via a SQL SELECT?

Comment: The actual query is constructed in the above code, I'll share the debug view for both... Filtering directly on cosmos works fine, the issue is present through .NET using IQueryable

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share debug info for the query running through .net. When we tried to fetch the record using .net LINQ code and were able to successfully fetch the record. Just wanted to make sure whether the format and datatype of the dates passing into .net code query are same.

Comment: Shared debug information

Answer (score 0):

Linq queries in cosmosdb's v3 SDK seem to not put milliseconds into the query if the date time used in the query does not have milliseconds.

A Linq query such as

```cs
var testTime = DateTime.Parse("2023-04-16T21:53:56Z").ToUniversalTime();

query
  .Where(x => x.MyTime >= testTime) 
  .OrderBy(x => x.MyTime)
  .Take(1);
```

will generate the following SQL

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root["MyTime"] >= "2023-04-16T21:53:56Z")) ORDER BY root["MyTime"] ASC
```

While I do have a record in cosmosdb with `2023-04-16T21:53:56.5Z` that record is not returned when the query does not have milliseconds in the time.

When changing the query to

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root["MyTime"] >= "2023-04-16T21:53:56.0Z")) ORDER BY root["MyTime"] ASC
```

the record is returned. It seems to me as if cosmosdb will choose query precision based on the precision of the date time in the query.

---

You can globally change the Newtonsoft JSON serializer for Dates, or in annotations on a per property basis. The format in the example below will always include 7 ms digits.

```cs
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
   {
      Converters = new List<JsonConverter>()
      {
         new IsoDateTimeConverter() 
         {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"
         }
      }
   };
   return settings;
};
```

This works even if you defined a custom serializer that does not use newtonsoft. The custom serializer is not used for LINQ queries. It always uses Newtonsoft for that.

---

Note that you should also store your DateTimes as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ`. Only adjusting it for the query is not enough for all cases. Ran into another similar issue later that was not resolved without changing how the dates are stored too. 3 millisecond places may be sufficient for many applications as javascript will cut off at the 3 ms point. But you have to be consistent for both querying and writing. Microsoft themselves seem to recommend this format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ` for storing dates in cosmosdb.